# How can I retrieve related queries data from Google Trends API using C#?

Tags: c#, google-developers-console, google-trends

In C#, how can I retrieve related queries data from Google Trends API ?

I have tried at my end but not getting proper response. Please help me out

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share (code) what you have tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much  
@Christos I have tried using python I got a output .

Here is a below code in python
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)
kw_list = ["Music"]
pytrends.build_payload(kw_list, cat=0, timeframe='today 12-m')
data = pytrends.related_queries()
topics = pytrends.related_topics()
print(data)
print(topics)

But I want to know how can acheive this via C#

Comment: @AntonyPradhap You are very welcome ! From a little search I found this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67044660/c-sharp-get-html-from-url-error-429-unknown, which is a relatively new post, not years back. If you read the accepted answer, you will see that way to go right now is the one you have already tried, via pytrends. On the other hand, since you want to achieve the same via C#, you will find there two deprecated projects, using C#.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much @Christos, I already tried on that. that was also not working.